# Get first element greater than a given number from a sorted list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, sorting

I have two lists. List B is like a database to which I need to compare each element of list A, one by one. Lets say

```
B = [0.6, 1.7, 3, 4.5]
A = [0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 4.5]
```

B is a sorted list, so for each A[i] whenever the algorithm finds a number which is >= A[i] in B, it should return that as the output. So my output should look something like:

```
C = [0.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 3, 3, 3, 4.5, 4.5]
```

Could you please suggest me the simplest solution, avoiding nested loops as much as possible?

Comment: Your output C makes no sense. 4.5 in B is greater than the first 8 enteries of A so as per your explanation, 4.5 should appear 8 times in C but the C you wrote has 4.5 only twice. This also applies to several other numbers like 3

Comment: @Bazingaa, he need the first greater element.

Comment: What if `B = [0.6, 1.7, 3, 3.9]`? Note that last element in `B` is smaller then last (two) elements in `A`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use a 3rd party library, one solution is NumPy via [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
import numpy as np

B = np.array([0.6, 1.7, 3, 4.5])
A = [0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 4.5]

res = B[np.searchsorted(B, A)]

array([ 0.6,  1.7,  1.7,  1.7,  3. ,  3. ,  3. ,  4.5,  4.5])
```

This will be more efficient than a sequential loop or an algorithm based on `bisect` from the standard library.

Answer (score 4):

Since `B` is sorted, you can use `bisect` to binary-search the correct value in `B`:

```
>>> B = [0.6, 1.7, 3, 4.5]
>>> A = [0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 4.5]
>>> import bisect
>>> [B[bisect.bisect_left(B, a)] for a in A]
[0.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 3, 3, 3, 4.5, 4.5]
```

This has complexity `O(alogb)`, with `a` and `b` being then lengths of `A` and `B` respectively. Assuming that `A` also is sorted, as in your example, you could also do it in `O(a+b)`:

```
i, C = 0, []
for a in A:
    while B[i] < a:
        i += 1
    C.append(B[i])
```

Note, however, that both approaches (as well as the other answers posted so far) will fail if `A` contains a number larger than any number in `B`.

Comment: We have thought in the same way. Anyway, +1

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Oh, I did not see that. Did you just edit that in before I posted my answer?

Comment: This deserves some credit, it *is* vectorised in one input, at least. +1

Answer (score 3):

Just a `next` would do (*if I understood you correctly*):

```
A = [0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 4.5]
B = [0.6, 1.7, 3, 4.5]

C = [next(b for b in B if b >= a) for a in A]

print(C)  # -> [0.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 3, 3, 3, 4.5, 4.5]
```

Comment: I like this for the list comprehension being being perfectly readable and natural english, even though it may be inefficient for longer lists.

Comment: @tobias_k I think that this question together with the posted answers demonstrates perfectly the power of Python. From very simple, *almost-natural-english* to much more sophisticated and very efficient methods.

Answer (score 2):

Since your given `B` list is sorted, you could use:

```
B = [0.6, 1.7, 3, 4.5]
A = [0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 4.5]

def first_greater_elem(lst, elem):
    for item in lst:
       if item >= elem:
         return item
```

Then just use a *list comprehension*.

```
C = [first_greater_elem(B,item) for item in A ]
```

Output

```
[0.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 3, 3, 3, 4.5, 4.5]
```

Another approach could be using `bisect_left` method from `bisect` package.

```
C = [B[bisect_left(B,item)] for item in A ]
```

Output

```
[0.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 3, 3, 3, 4.5, 4.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive way (destructive for original lists), **works also if list_a contains number larger than list_b**:

```
def pick(lst, ref, res=None):
  if res == None: res = []
  if len(lst) == 0: return res
  if ref[0] >= lst[0]:
    res.append(ref[0])
    lst.pop(0)
  elif len(ref) == 1 and ref[0] < lst[0]:
    # res.extend(lst) # if want to append the rest of lst instead of stop the loop
    # or do whathever is best for you
    return res
  else: ref.pop(0)
  pick(lst, ref, res)
  return res


list_b = [0.6, 1.7, 3, 3.9]
list_bb = [0.5]
list_a = [0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 4.5]

print(pick(list_a, list_b))
#=> [0.6, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 3, 3, 3]

print(pick(list_a, list_bb))
#=> []
```